# How to find the position of an object detected by Mask RCNN in an image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am Working on a computer vision project that identifies the infected leaves. What exactly I am doing is I am first detecting the leaf using Mask RCNN. Then I am segmenting the leaf. Next I am using Mask RCNN again to detect the infected areas within the segmented leaf. Now I want to find exactly on which position of the leaf the infection is located?
For example, this is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I want to identify in which all grids there is infection.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python

This might help to find the different features of contours, like area, perimeter, centroid, bounding box etc.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html